# Actionscript 3 button is using previous code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have one button for this slider. The slider has three sections.

Frame 24 has the first frame loaded. It is labeled "frame1".
  There is a button with the following code.
    rightButton_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bj_goRightTo2);

```
function bj_goRightTo2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay('1goesTo2');
}
```

Frame 25 starts the transition between the first and second frame. It is labeled "1goesTo2".

Frame 64 is the second frame loaded. It is labeled "frame2"
  Again there is a button with the next set with a gotoAndPlay('2goesTo3')

Frame 104 is the third frame loaded. It is labeled "frame3"
  Again there is a button with gotoAndPlay('3goesTo1').

But at the end of 3goesTo1 is a gotoAndStop('frame1').

At 'frame1' the code tells the button to gotoAndPlay('1goesTo2') but it actually only does the last gotoAndPlay('3goesTo1');

How can I get this button to refresh it's code?

Comment: is it the same button in every frame, with just a different event listener attached to it?

Comment: yes it is. Should I just create different buttons for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would`t try to change the eventhandler in the timeline.
Instead I would add one eventhandler in the parent clip and check the current label when the button receives a mouse click event.

Comment: Are you saying to write an if statement for the event handler like if(iAmOnARightLable){ do this event handler } ?

Comment: Not quiet. You just write one handler and call your other logic depending on the current frame of your clip.

like:
switch(myMovie.currentLabel)
{
    case "frame3":
        myClip.gotoAndPlay('3goesTo1').
        break
}

Comment: The switch worked. Larusso is my new favorite hero. Now all my button code is on one frame instead of 6 different frames spread out all over the place and much smaller too.

Comment: Give a a little more time with flash and you want to get away from timeline scripting completly ;)

Comment: I use to be pretty good with AS2 but stopped completely after AS3 came out just because I couldn't afford the upgrade. If you want to see what you did, check out bigjakesbbq.com. IE has the flash version. Non-IE has the JavaScript Version.